# WSO2 API manager -unable to connect secure websocket (WSS) in configured api publisher

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

i am using api manager 3.1.0 , i have configured web socket in api publisher , i m trying to access wss and ws . the problem is unable to access wss secure socket-.wss://localhost:8099/Notification/v1?access_token=xxx123 .
but i am able to access ws://localhost:9099/Notification/v1?access_token=xxx123.
can you please guide me, what i have to do configure to access wss,
please refer the screen clip shows unable to verify the first certificate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uENaT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJSUK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command given in documentation [1] for wss://. I'll post the sample command here. I think you have missed **'-n'** in the command.

```
wscat -n -c wss://localhost:8099/echowebsocket/1.0.0 -H "Authorization: Bearer [accesstoken]"
```

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/tutorials/create-and-publish-websocket-api/#step-3-invoke-a-websocket-api

Comment: i tried above method but, i  am getting error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND -n , find the link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJSUK.png,

Comment: For ws:// endpoint, does it work when you send the access token as "Authorization: Bearer [access_token]"?

Comment: yes,  ws:// working fine access token as "Authorization: Bearer [access_token]"

Comment: Hi @RajaMadhu, you should add '-n' before '-c'. Please try that and see if it solves the issue. I updated the answer with that information.

Comment: thanks! @tharika-madurapperuma, working fine, i think documented command is wscat -c -n wss:// not working.

Comment: Yes, that has to be updated. Thanks @RajaMadhu. Created an issue [1] https://github.com/wso2/docs-apim/issues/1471